# Capacitor with dielectrics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

An overview of the question:

[image]

Actually I tried this problem by taking K1 and K2 in parallel and their effective in series with K3.

But according to the answer given, they have taken K1 and a half of K3 in series and then K2 and another half of K3 in series and their effective in parallel. See below,

[image]

I just need to know which one is correct and the reason why it is correct. Can someone explain this to me(in detail if possible)? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
What I did:

[image]

What is the given answer:

[image]

Comment: Both should yield the same correct result. Have you tried your approach?

Comment: Yes i tried but both aren't matching

Comment: So post your calculations.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please read the [meta section](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange/) on the homework policy and try to edit your post accordingly :)

Comment: @polwel: I've posted the calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach would only be correct if there was a conductor separating K3 from the other dielectrics - which would enforce the same potential across K1 and K2.

But there is no such conductor, the potential is not the same, and that is why your method doesn't work (and the one given as the correct answer does).

Perhaps a diagram helps:

[image]

The voltage at any point on the conductors is the same; at the interface, there is NO conductor, and the potential is in fact different.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer!

Comment: @Floris: One thing I can't understand is that how parts of the same conductor have different potential. Then if they do won't a current flow in the conductor itself? Please help me.

Comment: @PreethamKrishna - there should be no difference in potential at different points of the same conductor. Why do you think there would be? I have added a diagram and some words to clarify.

Comment: Why does the charge distribution takes in the conductor but not on the interface .I mean your answer is lagging what would enforce same potential across K1 and K2

Comment: If the reasoning that the voltage across any part of the conductor is same,then we could perhaps split it into as many parallel parts as we wanted each time giving a different answer.

Comment: @navinstudent - you do NOT have the same potential across K1 and K2; that's the whole point of my answer (and the reason that OP's original approach to the problem does not work).

Comment: But your answer says "which would enforce the same potential across K1 and K2 " in the first para.

Comment: I said "approach would be correct IF there was a conductor". But there is no conductor, the potential is not enforced to be the same, and OP's method does not work.

Comment: @Floris: Oh ok there is no conductor there right. Thanks again!!!